# how to convert php to twig syntax

Tags: php, twig

Does anyone know how to covert this to twig?

```
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($discounts); $i++) { ?>
        <?php if ($i == (count($discounts) - 1)) { ?>
<?php echo $discounts[$i]['quantity']; ?> - <?php echo ($discounts[$i + 1]['quantity'] - 1); ?><br><?php echo $discounts[$i]['price']; ?> 
        
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

Tried something like this but couldn't get it to work

```
        {% for discount in discounts %}
    {% set next_item = discounts[loop.index0 + 1] %}
{{ discount.quantity }} - {{ next_item.quantity }}{{ text_discount }}<br>{{ discount.price }}
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given set (besides the missing closing `{% endfor %}`)? This looks like something you should better put in a service, such that you can write a unit test for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working snippet. I'm guessing your `twig` code just didn't ran because u didn't account for the "missing" discount when u go out-of-bounds. In `twig` you can use the `default` filter to catch this.

Also notice I'm using the special var `loop.index` which is 1-indexed, so there is no need to "calculate" the next index with `loop.index0 + 1`

```html
{% for discount in discounts %}
    From {{ discount.quantity }} To {{ discounts[loop.index].quantity|default('+') }}: {{ discount.price }}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/wt843s)

Comment: Made a mess off my question by trying to edit it but you absolutely nailed it. Thank you so much!